# Using regex with non-greedy second

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regex that matches a string and uses the non-greedy syntax so it stops at the first ending match. I need it to stop at the second ending match. How would I do that?

```
$text = "start text1 end text2 end text3 end";
$regex = "~start.+?end~";
preg_match($regex, $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
start text1 end
```

**Need Result**

```
start text1 end text2 end
```

Comment: You could do `start.+?end.+?end`.. You also might want to boundary `end` so `send`, `mend` etc. don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, you just have to repeat the expression sequence you want again.  There are a few ways to do it.  The simplest way is:

```
$text = "start text1 end text2 end text3 end";
$regex = "~start.+?end.+?end~";
preg_match($regex, $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

You may also want to use an exact quantifier to describe the pattern:

```
$text = "start text1 end text2 end text3 end";
$regex = "~start(.+?end){2}~";
preg_match($regex, $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

The "{2}" tells it to match everything in the parentheses before it exactly twice.